# Call AWS API Gateway from coldfusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, https, coldfusion, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call a dead simple function in AWS Lambda through AWS API Gateway.
This is the url that I tried to reach :
https://rt5b22m3l4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello

I called it in browser and it works fine. However when I use coldfusion 10 :

```
<cfscript>
    httpService = new http(method = "GET", charset = "utf-8", url = "https://rt5b22m3l4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello");

    httpService.addParam(name="accept-encoding", value="deflate;q=0", type="header");
    httpService.addParam(name="te", value="deflate;q=0", type="header");

    result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
    response = result.fileContent.toString();
    writeDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

It always return me

```
ErrorDetail I/O Exception: peer not authenticated
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: FYI : This is working fine in Coldfusion 11 and 2016 versions

Comment: _peer not authenticated_ errors are commonly caused by not having the appropriate certificate in the JVM's keystore.